# Why this saw shaper circuit does not work in reality?

Tags: opto-isolator

As part of the experiment, I decided to use an optocoupler in the saw shaper circuit. Although I managed to get the effect in the simulation, the actual design does not work on a breadboard. Please advice.[image]

[image]

Comment: @brhans "Does not work" means that I don't get a saw waveform at the output. I have added the screenshot of what I get. Thanks.

Comment: Are You powering this like in simulation? (+-15V)

Comment: @fifi_22 Yes, of course, with a separate PSU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input waveforms you're applying in your real circuit do not match those you're applying in the simulation.
In the sim, the square wave edges are aligned to the peaks of the triangle wave, but in your real circuit the screenshot shows that the square wave edges are aligned to the zero-cross points of the triangle wave.
This results in the opamp's configuration being switched at the wrong points in the triangle.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, R3 should equal R4. When the opto is not on, the gain of the op amp will be about +1, while with the opto on, the gain will be (-R4/R3).

Comment: @brhans Yes! You are absolutely right. I forgot to change the phase of the triangle to 270 degrees. I will check it. Thanks.

Comment: @brhans It works perfectly! Thanks a lot for your invaluable help and great eye ;)